# How to determine a threshold, statistically?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, standard-deviation, mean, threshold

I have a data from 6 months of 20 employees who sell cars and car insurance. I can capture the % of car insurance sold based on the numbers, but how can I figure a number(threshold) which tells me how is a good employee based on insurance sold. I am trying to figure it out statistically. Thank You.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what your end goal is.

Answer (score 3):

With statistical tools, you will only get relative indicators of performance, i.e. you will know how is a person doing compared to everyone else.

In this regard the most straightforward tool is probably the median value of whatever metric of performance you are looking at. Everyone with a value above the median will be part of the best half while those.

You can also raise the number of classes which allow for a more refined approach.For example, using quartiles, you will have your best 5 and worst 5 employees.

Otherwise, I believe it is better to wonder how much does an employee need to sell insurance for your business to be successful, which cannot be derived statistically but must be based on audit/accounting.